# Fix the dice value based on user count

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dice rolling game. I want the dice values from `6 to 12` to fall less frequently and the dice values from `2 to 5` to fall more frequently.

The dice value should fall like the below table

- If UserCount is `600or1200or1800...` then the dice value should be `6`
- If UserCount is `700or1400or2100...` then the dice value should be `7`
- If UserCount is `800or1600or2400...` then the dice value should be `8`
- If UserCount is `900or1800or2700...` then the dice value should be `9`
- If UserCount is `1000or2000or3000...` then the dice value should be `10`
- If UserCount is `1100or2200or3300...` then the dice value should be `11`
- If UserCount is `1200or2400or3600...` then the dice value should be `12`

So its like If the case is 600or1200 => 6 and 1200 => 12 then the dice value should be 6 If it is 1600or2400 => 8 and 1200or2400 =>12 then the dice value should be 8

For rest of the usercount the dice values should fall from `2 to 5` randomly.

I roll 2 dice at a time and each one is 6 sided. When i roll the dice if it falls between 2 to 5 then i will display the same value to the user. But if it is greater than 5 then i will check for the user count and have to fix the value as specified in the question

I maintain the user count in a `table`. This is an `windows application`.
Kindly Help.

I have come up with below code

```
public static String Roll(Int32 numberOfDice, Int32 numberOfSides, Int32 diceRolled)
        {

            if (numberOfDice <= 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Number of die must be greater than zero.");
            }

            if (numberOfSides <= 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Number of sides must be greater than zero.");
            }

            Random rnd = new Random((Int32)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            Int32 total = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 1; i < numberOfDice; i++)
            {

                Int32 roll = rnd.Next(2, numberOfSides);
                total += roll;

                if (total > 5)
                {
                    if (diceRolled % 6 == 0)
                    {
                        total = 6;
                    }
                    else if (diceRolled % 7 == 0)
                    {
                        total = 7;
                    }
                    else if (diceRolled % 8 == 0)
                    {
                        total = 8;
                    }
                    else if (diceRolled % 9 == 0)
                    {
                        total = 9;
                    }
                    else if (diceRolled % 10 == 0)
                    {
                        total = 10;
                    }
                    else if (diceRolled % 11 == 0)
                    {
                        total = 11;
                    }
                    else if (diceRolled % 12 == 0)
                    {
                        total = 12;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Dice.Roll(2, 12, diceRolled);
                    }
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total{0}", Convert.ToString(total));

            return Convert.ToString(total);
        }
```

Kindly suggest any improvements.

Comment: If UserCount is 600or1200 => 6.
But you also have If UserCount is 1200 => 12.
How do you handle this? Dice value can't be 6 and 12

Comment: What distribution do you want 2-5 to occur in? As though you rolled 2d6 and re-rolled if you got higher?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault If the case is 600or1200 => 6 and 1200 => 12 then the dice value should be 6 If it is 1600or2400 => 8 and 1200or2400 =>12 then the dice value should be 8

Comment: @Patashu I roll 2 dice at a time and each one is 6 sided. When i roll the dice if it falls between 2 to 5 then i will display the same value to the user. But if it is greater than 5 then i will check for the user count and have to fix the value as specified in the question.

Comment: @Vetti85 Please edit your question so it contains all of the necessary information to answer the question.

Comment: @Patashu I edited the question. Do you have any idea on how to do this.Pls help.I need it urgent!!!

Comment: @Vetti85 No, because I don't know what will happen if UserCount is 1200. Your logic makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Vetti85 I'm having a hard time understanding what you're looking for here. Perhaps it would help to clarify when you think about your problem as a Function, with inputs and outputs. What are the inputs? Is it the dice roll (1-6?) or the UserCount? What do you want to return when the given value is passed.

Comment: @JesseStromwick User can roll only once a pair of dice Which will display a random value between 2 to 12. If the value is between 2 to 5 then i will display the same value to user. If it greater than 5, the probability of falling the dice value between 6 to 12 should be for every 1000 users or else i should roll the dice again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
    public static int RollDice(int userCount)
    {
        //Reduce the user count ex: 600 => 6
        var reducedValue = userCount/100;

        //Process numbers 6-12
        for (int i = 6; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            //Create a trials list 
            var trials = new[]
                         {
                             reducedValue/i,
                             reducedValue/(i*2),
                             reducedValue/(i*3),
                         };

            //If any of the trials for this iteration passed
            //i.e. divided evenly, then return our index
            if (trials.Any(t => t == 1))
            {
                return i;
            } 
        }

        //Ok, just return a random number from 2 to 5
        var r = new Random();
        return  r.Next(2, 5);
    }
```

Comment: The OP has posted a comment that indicates that this pseudocode is not the correct algorithm.